# Trigger script when new folder has been added to a location

Tags: powershell, automation

I'm automating a process and already made a powershell script for that. Now I need to make something which will call that script everytime a new folder has been added to a specific location i.e. a new build is dropped.
What should I use for this. Is WCF too much? And if not, got any leads for that? Any useful links.
Or is another powershell script better for that?

Keep in mind I need to check subfolders too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personnaly I'ld use System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

```
$folder = 'c:\myfoldertowatch'
$filter = '*.*'                             
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter 
$fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = $true              
$fsw.NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName' # just notify directory name events
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {  ... do my stuff here } # and only when is created
```

Use this to stop watching event

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
```

Comment: But this script should be running all the time, since I never know when a new build is dropped. How safe and stable would this implementation be?

Comment: You can create an application (windows service maybe?) in .net (vb/c#) using IO.FileSystemWatcher class that do same work. Personally I use a powershell script on a production server that do the same thing from about one year (maintenance reboot excluded ;) )

Comment: Tested. Working :D Thanks a lot to both Christian and Shay. I'm very new to this, and this help means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{
    Path = "d:\temp"
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true #monitor subdirectories within the specified path
}

$event = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw –EventName Created -SourceIdentifier fsw -Action {

    #test if the created object is a directory
    if(Test-Path -Path $EventArgs.FullPath -PathType Container)
    {
        Write-Host "New directory created: $($EventArgs.FullPath)"  
        # run your code/script here
    }
}
```

Comment: Using [IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName'  there is no need to test if is a folder.