# Using PowerShell to grant security rights to multiple folders.

Tags: powershell

We have an in-house application that creates a folder, with 8 sub-folders, whenever a new project is started (keeping the same file structure in every folder).  Our fileserver sets the security to the top level folder, breaking any specific sub-folder rights.

I'm looking at using a[This System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529315/trigger-script-when-new-folder-has-been-added-to-a-location) to automate the PowerShell, once the folders have been created.

The PowerShell I'm looking at using is:

```
    New-Item F:\Engineering Projects\TPS\Documents\ –Type Directory
Get-Acl F:\Engineering Projects\TPS\Documents\ | Format-List

$acl = Get-Acl F:\Engineering Projects\TPS\Documents\
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Users","Read", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl F:\Folder $acl

Get-Acl F:\Folder  | Format-List
```

I'm not very experienced with PowerShell, Exchange things being the main area where I've experienced it.  Obviously that script is more of a generic starting point for me; my question is, would I run this script multiple times (for each folder requiring specific permissions), or can I incorporate multiple folder permissions within one script?

Comment: You can add multiple ACEs to an ACL and then set it once with `Set-Acl`.

Comment: After re-reading my post, I was a bit unclear.

Comment: Please disregard my last post - didn't use Shift/Enter.

-Our inhouse application creates a folder with 8 or so subfolders.  The top folder gets created numerically, while the sub folders contain the same names every time.  

-Would you advise using a PowerShell script on that, something like iCalcs, or a different method altogether?

Comment: Both PowerShell and `icacls` should work just fine.