# Detecting csv files in newly sub-folder in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a folder called C:\2014-15 and new sub folders are created every month which contain csv files i.e

1. C:\2014-15\Month 1\LTC
2. C:\2014-15\Month 2\LTC
3. C:\2014-15\Month 3\LTC

How to write a script which would detect when a LTC sub folder is created for every month and move the csv files to N:\Test?

UPDATED:

```
$folder = 'C:\2014-15'
$filter = '*.*'
$destination = 'N:Test\'
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
IncludeSubdirectories = $true 
NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host
Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $destination 
}
```

The error I get is:

Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot subscribe to event. A subscriber with source identifier       'FileCreated' already exists.
At line:8 char:34
+ $onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent <<<<  $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.IO.FileSystemWatcher:FileSystemWatcher) [Register-ObjectEvent], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SUBSCRIBER_EXISTS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterObjectEventCommand

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: Hi. I don't have any code which works at all. I have used FileSystemWatcher and move-item.

Comment: What's the script run schedule? Daily (overnight)?

Comment: Please explain what you've tried and why it doesn't work (error messages?) If the folders are moved elsewhere then it seems you move a folder as soon as it exists, as the folder should usually be empty.

Comment: The error has occurred because you are testing, having already run `Register-ObjectEvent`. Would it be easier if your script was run monthly, and creates the /Month x/LTC directories **as well** as moving the log files?

Comment: To unregister the event: `Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "FileCreated" -Force`

Comment: Thank You ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF But how will I get the script to move new files when a LTC subfolder is created every month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Credit to this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529315/trigger-script-when-new-folder-has-been-added-to-a-location)

Notify on a different event: `[IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName'`. This removes the need for `$filter` since filename events are not relevant.

You should also notify for renamed folders **and** created folders, making your final script something like this

```
$folder = 'C:\2014-15'
$destination = 'N:\Test'

$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder -Property @{
   IncludeSubdirectories = $true
   NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName'
}

$created = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {
   $item = Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
   If ($item.Name -ilike "LTC") {
      # do stuff:
      Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination $destination
   }
}

$renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Renamed -Action {
   $item = Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
   If ($item.Name -ilike "LTC") {
      # do stuff:
      Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination $destination 
   }
}
```

From the same console you can unregister since that console knows about `$created` and `$renamed`:

```
Unregister-Event $created.Id
Unregister-Event $renamed.Id
```

Otherwise you need to use this which is bit uglier:

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier Created -Force
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier Renamed -Force
```

Also, thanks for the question. I didn't realise these event captures existed in powershell until now...

Comment: The script only copies the 2014-15 folder with empty content into the 'N:Test' destination folder.

Comment: You will need to change `Copy-Item` to perform the exact command you need. If they are they in the LTC folder, are they instantly crrated when the folder is created?

Comment: I changed the Copy-Item to: Copy-Item -Path $item -Destination $destination but this copies the LTC folder with no csv files but I need to copy the csv files within the LTC folder only.

Comment: Try `Copy-Item -Path "$item\*.csv" -Destination $destination`

Comment: I used Copy-Item -Path "$item\*.csv" but it only copies some files only

Comment: You should expect that. You wanted the event to fire when the directory is created - at that particular time, the files do not exist yet. By the time your script catches up it will find a few files, perhaps not all have been copied/created there before the script is complete.